# django-admin2 together with django-debug-toolbar are in conflict

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I tried to use django-admin2 in my project. And after 2 hours of struggling with:

```
djadmin2.default.autodiscover()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'default'
```

I find [this](https://github.com/pydanny/django-admin2/issues/392) ticket. It says that debug-toolbar are conflicted with DJ-admin2.

Anyone knows how to use django-admin2 with DJ-debug-toolbar?

And why debug-toolbar make conflict ?

Here is my requirements.pip:

```
Django==1.6.5
psycopg2==2.5.2
selenium==2.40.0
django-debug-toolbar
Pillow==2.4.0
South==0.8.4
django-admin2==0.6.1
django-braces==1.3.1
django-crispy-forms==1.4.0
django-floppyforms==1.2.0
```